# How to get a input value without submit php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to get a input value with ajax/jquery without refresh and pass the value to php, but my code its not working fine, on javasciprt the alert its not working so i have this html

```
<input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad"
       placeholder="1-10"
       min="1" max="10" value="1" />
```

and before this there is jquery script that is

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>


$( "#cantidad" ).change(function() {

     var model=$('#cantidad').val();
    alert(model);


});

</script>
```

so this is not working, and if were, how can i pass the value to php ?

Comment: You are not calling `getHouseModel()` in your code.

Comment: yes i was, anyway i change the code with change funciton, still without working ;(

Comment: If the simple change approach isn't working it's probably because you are running that code before the element exists. Wrap it in `$(function(){ /* your code*/})`

Comment: yea i fixed with the reaady function, but how to pass the value to php ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you declare a new function inside the click event handler but never call that function.

The following two approaches show how to make what you have work.

Then use ajax to send data to php

```js
function getHouseModel() {
  var model = $('#cantidad').val();
  console.log('From getHouseModel', model);
}
// make sure document is ready
$(function(){
    // using declared function as handler
    $(".comprarH3").click(getHouseModel);

    // or without declared function
    $(".comprarH3").click(function() {
      var model = $('#cantidad').val();
      console.log('Basic', model);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad"
       placeholder="1-10"
       min="1" max="10" value="1" />
       
       <button class='comprarH3'>Click me</button>
```

Comment: ty the php problem ?

Comment: Study some ajax with php tutorials

Answer (score 0):

In the click handler, directly call your code instead of just having a function being declared. Else declare this function outside the handlers, and then just call within the click handler.
Also ensure that document.ready is the global container of any such code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".comprarH3" ).click(function() {
       /* function getHouseModel(){  */
        var model=$('#cantidad').val();
        alert(model);

         /* }   */

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i fixed it with the ready function, TY!! do you know how can i pass the value to php ?

Comment: You need to have service written out there which is called by the ajax https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/671437/Creating-Web-Service-Using-PHP-Within-Minutes